Database connection error while doing GitHub action ci/cd
I am trying GitHub Actions for CI with FastAPI app.
Here is my workflow .yml file. It runs all the way without errors until the test start "test with pytest".
name: Build and Deploy Code

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  job1:
    environment:
      name: testing
    env:
      DATABASE_HOSTNAME:  ${{secrets.DATABASE_HOSTNAME}}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PORT}}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD}}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${{secrets.DATABASE_NAME}}
      DATABASE_NAME_TEST: ${{secrets.DATABASE_NAME_TEST}}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${{secrets.DATABASE_USERNAME}}
      SECRET_KEY: ${{secrets.SECRET_KEY}}
      ALGORITHM: ${{secrets.ALGORITHM}}
      ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES: ${{secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES}}
    
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${{secrets.DATABASE_PASSWORD}}
          POSTGRES_DB: ${{secrets.DATABASE_NAME}}
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
          
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: pulling git repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Install python version 3.10
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: "3.10"
      - name: update pip
        run: python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      - name: insatll all dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: test with pytest
        run: |
          pip install pytest
          pip install httpx
          pytest

Error:
dsn = 'host=*** dbname=*** user=*** *** port=***'
connection_factory = None, cursor_factory = None
kwargs = {'dbname': '***', 'host': '***', 'password': '***', 'port': ***, ...}
kwasync = {}

    def connect(dsn=None, connection_factory=None, cursor_factory=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Create a new database connection.
    
        The connection parameters can be specified as a string:
    
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=*** ***")
    
        or using a set of keyword arguments:
    
            conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="***", ***)
    
        Or as a mix of both. The basic connection parameters are:
    
        - *dbname*: the database name
        - *database*: the database name (only as keyword argument)
        - *user*: user name used to authenticate
        - *password*: password used to authenticate
        - *host*: database host address (defaults to UNIX socket if not provided)
        - *port*: connection port number (defaults to *** if not provided)
    
        Using the *connection_factory* parameter a different class or connections
        factory can be specified. It should be a callable object taking a dsn
        argument.
    
        Using the *cursor_factory* parameter, a new default cursor factory will be
        used by cursor().
    
        Using *async*=True an asynchronous connection will be created. *async_* is
        a valid alias (for Python versions where ``async`` is a keyword).
    
        Any other keyword parameter will be passed to the underlying client
        library: the list of supported parameters depends on the library version.
    
        """
        kwasync = {}
        if 'async' in kwargs:
            kwasync['async'] = kwargs.pop('async')
        if 'async_' in kwargs:
            kwasync['async_'] = kwargs.pop('async_')
    
        dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
>       conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
E       psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "***" (::1), port *** failed: FATAL:  database "***" does not exist

/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.10.14/x64/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:122: OperationalError

I have two databases and I set all secrets in the GitHub environment, after checking in the GitHub action logs it seems it getting all secrets keys but when it starts testing, it starts encountering this error
